# How to add new shell commands to a subprocess in Python 3.7?

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, python-3.7

I am trying to find a way to add commands to stdin of an already open shell process in Python 3.7. But I can't seem to find a solution.

I have tried a number of solutions with no luck.

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen('pwd > test', shell=True, stdin=PIPE, text=True) # works

p1.communicate('pwd > test1')                                    # doesn't work
p1.communicate(input='pwd > test2')                              # doesn't work
p1.communicate('pwd > test3\n')                                  # doesn't work
p1.stdin.write('pwd > test4')                                    # doesn't work
p1.stdin.write('pwd > test5\n')                                  # doesn't work
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no "already open shell process" that accepts commands in your code. A shell used to launch commands *doesn't* receive commands via stdin. Did you mean to launch an interactive shell instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this if your command is itself a shell, but not if it is a command which either exits (as `pwd` does), or one which grabs stdin as it's own input. The following should work - note that you don't need `shell=True`, and that you need to flush the writes to `stdin`:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p1 = subprocess.Popen('bash', stdin=PIPE, text=True)

p1.stdin.write("xeyes\n")
p1.stdin.flush()
```

You can track this more closely by doing e.g.:

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen('pwd', shell=True, stdin=PIPE, text=True)
p1.pid
```

Then looking at the process id in a shell:

`ps -ef |grep <PID>`

You'll see: `sh <defunct>` which shows that the process is dead and no longer available to communicate with (but still shows up as python is holding a reference to it, which disappears when python exits).

If you try to write to stdin you'll get:

> BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe